# Redirect from .htaccess does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and i want to make it always show as www.mysite .com i put that code in .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

now the url shows as www but the website is not shown the browser said "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Note: .htcaccess do not have any code but this few lines i wrote

does i did anything wrong or i miss something??? please help

Edit:

before I add the above code the .htaccess had the following code but not direct to www i remove it :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]

# END WordPress
```

could that be updated to solve my problem?

Comment: If there is no other .htaccess and no other rule in this .htaccess then above code should have worked. Try it a different browser.

Comment: i try it in Mozilla and Chrome but nothing happened the same problem

Comment: Is your rewrite mode is activated ? If you are on linux 

a2enmod rewrite

Comment: Make sure .htaccess is enabled (put som grabage text in .htaccess and see if you get 500 error in browser).

Comment: 500 error is working so the .htaccess is enabled

Comment: you can try this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @neo still the same problem shown in the broswer

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it at windows server it will not work if it is window you have to create web.config file n for linux it should be .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Ok so  `Wordpress` is also there. Make sure to do these 2 things:

1. Put your `301` rule **above WP's rules** i.e. just below `RewriteBase` line
2. Update WP settings to have your site address with `www`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```